# Finding Redis data by last update

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis and I want to use the following scheme:

key: EMPLOYEE_*ID*
value: *EMPLOYEE DATA*

I was thinking of adding a time stamp to the end of the key, but I'm not sure if that'll even help. Basically I want to be able to get a list of employees who are the most stale ie having been updated. What's the best way to accomplish this in Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep another key with the data about employees (key names) and the update's timestamp - the best candidate for that is a Sorted Set. To maintain that key's data integrity, you'll have update it with pertinent changes whenever you update one the employees' keys.

With that data structure in place, you can easily get the keys names of the recently-updated employees with the `ZRANGE` command.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to filter by expiration time? You could set the same expiration to all keys and update the expiration each time the key is updated. Then with a LUA script you could iterate through the keys and filter by expiration time. Those with smaller expiration time are those who are not updated.

This would work with some assumptions, it depends on how your system works. Also the approach is O(N) with respect to the number of employees. So if on one side you can save space, it will not scale well with the number of entries and the frequency of scan.

Comment: That's a very creative approach but it is likely to be less performant as it does a full scan of the database.

Comment: @ItamarHaber, I haven't met the phrase 'That's a very creative approach but ..' in that context before. I like it... :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber well how many empoyees do we expect to have?  not sure, even if u have a giant  company your employ number will not exceed couple of thousands. Of coure if you have to run this query several times it would not be a good idea, but for a periodic check it is absolutely valid.

Comment: @xbirkettx the number of employees is indeed an important metric to have, but more important is the overall number of keys in the database - this number is what dictates the approach's performance.

Comment: @itamarHaber I agree is not the most efficient approach but I guess it was worth mentioning for some easy case :)

Comment: @xbirkettx definitely, just wanted to point out the inherent inefficiency in a full scan.